# Convert an array to an array of arrays of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I try to convert this simple array to an array of arrays of arrays

```
string[] test = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

I am looking for the fellow output once serialised by JSON.NET.

> [[["a"]],[["b"]],[["c"]]]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an array of array of arrays, you'd use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method, and use it to project each string into an array of arrays, with the original string in the inner array.

```
var arrayOfArrayOfArrays = test.Select(s => new[] { new[] { s } }).ToArray();
```

And of course don't forget to call ToArray at the end, otherwise you'll end up with an IEnumerable of array of arrays.

Comment: Nice exactly what i was looking for.. didn't though about using LINQ. This make this whole stuff a lots easier.

Comment: How would you do it based on a 2D array this time to have a result like [[[1],[2]],[[2],[4]],[[3],[6]]] ? it is a lots harder ?

Comment: Found it. var arrayOfArrayOfArrays2 = test.Select(s => new[] { new[] { s.GetValue(0) }, new[] { s.GetValue(1) } }).ToArray(); this could be taken from a 2D array.